# discord py get guild ID in task

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello I am new to discord py I would like to use the guild id in my task how do I get to this in my task I hope someone can help me

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord.commands import slash_command, Option

import aiosqlite

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.DB = "database.db"
        self.count_channel_task.start()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self,):
        async with aiosqlite.connect(self.DB) as db:
            await db.execute(
                """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS count_channels (
                guild_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                channel_id INTEGER,
                channel_name TEXT
                )"""
            )
    

    @tasks.loop(seconds=30)
    async def count_channel_task(self):
        for guild in self.guilds:
            print(guild)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord.commands import slash_command, Option

import aiosqlite

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.DB = "database.db"
        self.test.start()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self,):
        async with aiosqlite.connect(self.DB) as db:
            await db.execute(
                """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS count_channels (
                guild_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                channel_id INTEGER,
                channel_name TEXT
                )"""
            )
    

    @tasks.loop(minutes=5)
    async def test(self):
        if not self.bot.guilds:
            self.test.restart()
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            print(guild.id)



def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

Comment: Hi I tried but it comes up AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'guilds'

Comment: @Justin Hi, hmm can you send a bot class?

Comment: Hi, I have put all my code from my cog

Comment: @Justin Changed the answer, it should work

Comment: You can write to me personally in Discord, I will answer there immediately </Rick>#4710

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).